# Reset $rootscope value used to hide back button

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide, angularjs-rootscope

I am using ng-hide to hide back button and show it in required pages. In app.js I have following code where i am declaring the initial value to true:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'ui.mask', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'input-digits', 'input-phone','dailyTips']).run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.hideNavBackBtn = true;
});
```

And after that in each controller where I want back button to be shown I am setting value as:

```
$rootScope.hideNavBackBtn = false;
```

But when I come back to the previous page the back button is there, this should not happen. Only for the specific pages where I have declared value as false the back button should show.

How to rectify this issue?

What my understanding is app.js is already loaded so when I come back the $rootScope value will remain as false. If my understanding is correct how to rectify it?

In app.js file config function were I have declared different state like:

```
.state('home.overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        templateUrl: 'modules/Overview.html',
    })
```

In this if I define controller and set value to true. Then the back button will not be visible. But then I have to define the $rootscope value in every state I create, that dont look like viable solution.

Comment: What back do you use? A browser one or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$rootScope.hideNavBackBtn = true;` is only executed once, when your Angular module is initialized.

You change the value (`$rootScope.hideNavBackBtn = false;`) only in some controller to set it to `false`. You never set it to `true` again.

what you can do is to set it to `true` on the `ng-click` of this button.

Comment: I think ng-init would be better than ng-click.